# PowerBI DAX - adding date filter to DAX Query

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to add a date condition to the DAX query below, and I am struggling to find something to work.  I basically want to filter on the Combination.Expiration Date column.  For example, I dont want the query to return anything if there is no expiration date, or the expiration date is in the past.  Below is the current DAX query.

```
List of Requirement values = 
VAR __DISTINCT_VALUES_COUNT = DISTINCTCOUNT('Combination'[Requirement])
VAR __MAX_VALUES_TO_SHOW = 90
RETURN
    IF(
        __DISTINCT_VALUES_COUNT > __MAX_VALUES_TO_SHOW,
        CONCATENATE(
            CONCATENATEX(
                TOPN(
                    __MAX_VALUES_TO_SHOW,
                    VALUES('Combination'[Requirement]),
                    'Combination'[Requirement],
                    ASC
                ),
                'Combination'[Requirement],
                ", ",
                'Combination'[Requirement],
                ASC
            ),
            ", etc."
        ),
        CONCATENATEX(
            VALUES('Combination'[Requirement]),
            'Combination'[Requirement],
            ", ",
            'Combination'[Requirement],
            ASC
        )
    )
```

Can anyone help me add a date filter within this?  I am new to PowerBI, and I am struggling on this piece.

Comment: Add a surrounding IF statement that executes your current query if expirationdate < today or expirationdate = ""?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VALUES('Combination'[Requirement])` gives you a table with all the Requirement values in the Combination table.

If you want to exclude certain result from that table, you need to apply a filter to that table.

You have two options:

```
Option 1:
VAR tbl_values = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Combination'[Requirement]),
                'Combination'[Expiration Date] = BLANK() ||
                'Combination'[Expiration Date] < TODAY())

Option 2:
VAR tbl_filtered = FILTER('Combination', 
                'Combination'[Expiration Date] = BLANK() ||
                'Combination'[Expiration Date] < TODAY())
```

Then you can replace the VALUES in your measure

```
List of Requirement values = 
VAR __DISTINCT_VALUES_COUNT = DISTINCTCOUNT('Combination'[Requirement])
VAR __MAX_VALUES_TO_SHOW = 90
VAR tbl_filtered = FILTER('Combination', 
                'Combination'[Expiration Date] = BLANK() ||
                'Combination'[Expiration Date] < TODAY())

RETURN
    IF(
        __DISTINCT_VALUES_COUNT > __MAX_VALUES_TO_SHOW,
        CONCATENATE(
            CONCATENATEX(
                TOPN(
                    __MAX_VALUES_TO_SHOW,
                    tbl_filtered,
                    'Combination'[Requirement],
                    ASC
                ),
                'Combination'[Requirement],
                ", ",
                'Combination'[Requirement],
                ASC
            ),
            ", etc."
        ),
        CONCATENATEX(
            tbl_filtered,
            'Combination'[Requirement],
            ", ",
            'Combination'[Requirement],
            ASC
        )
    )
```

Comment: This works awesome!  Thank you!  And if I wanted to make it based on date, I would think it would be something like 'Combination'[Expiration Date] <  DATE ( "2018", "1", "5" ))?

Comment: Yes, or even better have a slicer where you can pick the date and then use SELECTEDVALUE(Slicer[Date])

Comment: Ultimately, I am trying to find a date events that occur between two dates (today and 30 days from now, 30 and 60 days, and 60 and 90 days).  I am trying something along the lines of VAR tbl_filtered = FILTER('Combination', 
                'Combination'[Expiration Date] >= TODAY() &&
                'Combination'[Expiration Date] <= TODAY(DATEADD()
I am really struggling to get the dateadd to function in this instance

Comment: Long term goal is to have a table/matrix with persons name, then a concatenated list requirements expired/missing, 30 days out, 60 days out., 90 days out.  I added another column with the same query above, just to see how that would react.  In the second instance of said column (different name), it includes everything, like the query is no longer working.

Comment: VAR tbl_filtered = FILTER('Combination', 
                'Combination'[Expiration Date] > TODAY() &&
                'Combination'[Expiration Date] < TODAY() + 30) seemed to do the triick

Comment: DATEADD doesn't work in that way, I tend to use EDATE or EOMONTH to compare to different months.

Comment: I did look into those too, but I am unsure how to make either of those work in strictly day intervals?

Comment: yeah, with days is just as you did.